# Angular NgForm: reset exact form filed value does not make it valid

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-forms

I have a form on a component's template:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="submitLogin(loginForm)" #loginForm="ngForm">
  <mat-input-container>
    <input matInput [placeholder]="'User Name'" ngModel name="username" autofocus required>
  </mat-input-container>
  <br>
  <mat-input-container>
    <input matInput [placeholder]="'Password'" ngModel type="password" name="password" required>
  </mat-input-container>
  <br>
  <button [disabled]="loginForm.invalid" mat-raised-button type="submit">
    Login
  </button>
</form>
```

And here is my component's submit handler:

```js
public submitLogin(loginForm: NgForm) {
  return this.authService.login(loginForm.value)
    .subscribe(
      res => this.router.navigate(['/customers']),
      error => loginForm.controls.password.reset() // this place!
    );
}
```

It works and on login error (passing some random values) I see

[image]

**Question**. How can I reset exact fileld on the Form and make it truly pristine and untouched? So it should be valid without marking it with red "invalid" border on the UI.

Right after `loginForm.controls.password.reset()` I see that `loginForm.controls.password.touched` is **false** and `loginForm.controls.password.pristine` is **true**, but I see also that `loginForm.controls.password.status` is "**INVALID**". If I hack it and directly assign the "**VALID**" value to the `status` property, the red invalid border disappeares, but it breaks lost-focus invalidation in case I focus on that filed and then go away without any input. There should be a legal way to reset form filed and make it valid in the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This seems to be a known issue. According to **[this](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/4190#issuecomment-305222426)** the error state is calculated like:

```
isInvalid && (isTouched || isSubmitted)
```

So when you have submitted your form, the `isSubmitted` flag is set to `true`, thus the condition is fulfilled and your field is shown as red. There are some workarounds, if you were to reset the whole form, you could use `resetForm` instead, but here you only want to reset one field, so...

There is an **[suggestion](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/7522#issuecomment-334478881)** to use **[`ErrorStateMatcher`](https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview#changing-when-error-messages-are-shown)**:

```html
<input matInput 
   [placeholder]="'Password'" 
   ngModel type="password" 
   name="password" required 
   [errorStateMatcher]="matcher">
```

ErrorStateMatcher:

```ts
export class MyErrorStateMatcher implements ErrorStateMatcher {
  isErrorState(control: FormControl | null, form: FormGroupDirective | NgForm | null): boolean {
    // show errors when touched and invalid
    return (control.invalid && control.touched);
  }
}
```

and declare a ErrorStateMatcher in your TS:

```ts
matcher = new MyErrorStateMatcher();
```

Seems to work: **[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hbq2uv-qi5pbr?file=app/input-error-state-matcher-example.ts)**

Comment: Thanks for demo and explanations! But the issue with broken invalidation on the lost-focus event is still there. I forked your StackBlitz ([link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hbq2uv-4fuv53)) to demonstrate that I can easily achieve the same result with just setting `loginForm.controls.password.setErrors(null)` (the same approach as the destructive setting `loginForm.controls.password.status = "VALID"`). But I need to get this filed invalid when I focus on it and then leave it without any changes.

Comment: Well I was suggesting `loginForm.controls.password.setErrors(null)` first in my post, but noticed, the button is enabled after reset since errors are removed and password is no longer required :) But back to your question, you mean you want to show the error when `touched`? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hbq2uv-z3xxvp?file=app/input-error-state-matcher-example.ts

Comment: Yes, with your last update the issue had been resolved, thanks a lot!

Comment: Great, glad to hear! I'll update my answer accordingly :)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `markAs` existing functions

Something like this

```
this.loginForm.controls.password.reset()
this.loginForm.controls.password.markAsPristine()
this.loginForm.controls.password.markAsUntouched()
this.loginForm.controls.password.updateValueAndValidity()
```

These are actual API functions for when you want to enforce a particular state and don’t want to depend entirely on Angular decision of what should the be the state of the field

Check [here](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#!%23updateValueAndValidity-anchor) how to better use the `updateValueAndValidity` method

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not matter, due to (as I mentioned on Question) the control that had been reset is already pristine and untouched. The problem is in it's status wich remains "INVALID"...

Comment: I have edited my answer to include the additional call that solves your problem. Also included the link to angular documentation where you can check the usage of it