# Angular 5 Form reset displays error back - ReactiveFormsModule

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms

I have below code where I just submit few details and reset the form after successful submission.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.initContactForm();    
}

initContactForm(){
    this.contactForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            fullname: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(2), Validators.maxLength(30)])],
            email: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required])],
            phone: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10), Validators.maxLength(12)])],
            subject: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.maxLength(25), Validators.minLength(5)])],
            message: ['', Validators.compose([Validators.required, Validators.minLength(10), Validators.maxLength(200)])]
        });
}

onSubmit(model){
    if (this.contactForm.valid){
        this.contactModel = model;
        this.dataService.sendContactMessage(this.contactModel).then((resp) => {
            if (resp){
                this.openSnackBar('Message has been sent', 'Done');    
                this.contactForm.reset();
                this.contactForm.updateValueAndValidity();
                this.contactForm.setErrors(null);
            }else{
                console.log('Error');
            }

        });
    }else{
        alert('Invalid form');
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<form autocomplete="off" [formGroup]="contactForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(contactForm.value)">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col m4 s12">
            <mat-form-field>
                <input oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" maxlength="30" matInput type="text" placeholder="Full Name" value="" name="fullname" formControlName="fullname" required>
                <mat-error *ngIf="contactForm.controls['fullname'].hasError('required')">
                    <strong>Please enter your Fullname</strong>
                </mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
         </div>
         <div class="col m4 s12">
            <mat-form-field>
                <input matInput type="email" placeholder="Email Address" value="" name="email" formControlName="email" required email>
                <mat-error *ngIf="contactForm.controls['email'].hasError('required')">
                     <strong>Please enter your Email Id</strong>
                </mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
         </div>
         <div class="col m4 s12">
            <mat-form-field>
                <input matInput type="tel" placeholder="Contact Number" value="" name="contact" formControlName="phone" required tel>
                <mat-error *ngIf="contactForm.controls['phone'].hasError('required')">
                    <strong>Please enter your Contact number</strong>
                 </mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col m12 s12">
            <mat-form-field>
                <input matInput type="text" oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" maxlength="25" placeholder="Subject" value="" name="subject" formControlName="subject" required>
                <mat-error *ngIf="contactForm.controls['subject'].hasError('required')">
                    <strong>Please enter Subject</strong>
                </mat-error>
             </mat-form-field>
        </div>
        <div class="col s6 s12">
            <mat-form-field>
                <textarea matInput type="text" style="resize:none;" oninput="javascript: if (this.value.length > this.maxLength) this.value = this.value.slice(0, this.maxLength);" maxlength="200" placeholder="Message" value="" name="message" formControlName="message"
                rows="5" required></textarea>
                <mat-error *ngIf="contactForm.controls['message'].hasError('required')">
                    <strong>Please enter your Message</strong>
                </mat-error>
            </mat-form-field>
        </div>
     </div>
     <div class="row margin-top20">
        <div class="col l6 push-l6 s12 right-align">
            <button type="submit" mat-button class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
        </div>
        </div>
</form>
```

Whenever I call `contactForm.reset()` values get cleared but all the errors show up again.

I've tried various other ways to clear this as below:

- Tried calling `initContactForm()` after `form reset`
- Tried looping through each form control and used `markAsUntouched()`, `markAs Pristine()` etc.,

**Here it is**

```
Object.keys(this.contactForm.controls).forEach(key => {
    this.contactForm.controls[key].setErrors(null);
    this.contactForm.controls[key].updateValueAndValidity();
});
```

Am I left with anything else to try. I am still not able to clear the errors after `reset`.. Hope to get some help.

Comment: I guess you need to set markAsTouched` to false to whole form

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid No luck bro.. :(

Comment: Check this answer by Harry Ninh
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48217303/9499885

Comment: @borutc.. Awesome. Fantastic. Marvelous.. You just removed my overhead. Thank you so much bro.. :)

Answer (score 2):

As soon as you reset the form, values are cleared.

`Validators.required` will then be processed and your field will become invalid as it is empty.
If you want to show errors only when user has interacted with the form control, add this to your conditions:

```
mat-error *ngIf="contactForm.controls['phone'].hasError('required') && contactForm.controls['phone'].dirty"
```

Comment: Nope bro.. Even though the error message isn't displayed, the control is still invalid.. :(

Comment: And its normal as your `Validators.required` will return an error. You'll see that at the very beginning, before any interaction, your form is already invalid.

Comment: But even though I set `form.setErrors(null)` and `form.updateValueAndValidity()` still form has errors. How come.. :(

Comment: Once again: it's normal. You can't bypass form's validation workflow. When you use `form.updateValueAndValidity()`, then validation is processed and errors are set. `form.setErrors(null)` works only if you manage the whole form's validation manually.

Comment: Try just NOT TO CALL updateValueAndValidity() function after clearing errors

Comment: `updateValueAndValidity()` is called before clearing errors. It still won't change the issue, as automatic validation is set through the formBuilder, then `setErrors(null)` manually will have no effects

Comment: So, what's the ultimate way to overcome this? Now even though error message is not displayed, control will be invalid and a red underline will be displayed under control. How can I overcome this?

Comment: Change the CSS to display the red line only when the input is both invalid and dirty. Angular decorates the input with such classes (like ng-invalid etc)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this after you reset your form

```
    this.contactForm.markAsPristine();
    this.contactForm.markAsUntouched();
    this.contactForm.updateValueAndValidity();
```

Comment: Doesn't work, dude!