# Best way of reset form angular7 form reset

Tags: angular, angular7

reset form angular after saving data successfully

Comment: which form you are using template driven or Model-Driven?

Comment: reactive form i am using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Template Driven Form :

**HTML code**

```
<form #myForm="ngForm" (submit)="resetForm(myForm)"> ... </form>
```

**TS Code**

```
resetForm(form: NgForm){
form.reset(); // or form.resetForm();
}
```

In Reactive Form

**HTML code**

```
<form (ngSubmit)="resetForm()">
</form>
```

**TS code**

```
// Declare your form 
myform: FormGroup;

resetForm() {
 if (this.myform.valid) {
   this.myform.reset();
 }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call [**`reset()`**](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#reset) on the [**`FormGroup`**](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup) instance that represents your form to reset it.

Answer (score 1):

The default .reset() method will wipe the inputs but it will not correctly reset the validators. If you're using validators, see this solution (or the main solution to the question if resetting after a submit).

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53522125/5108158

Answer (score 0):

i got solution 
form.reset(); // or form.resetForm();