# How to reset Angular Material error as if form wasn't submitted?

Tags: angular, typescript, forms, validation, angular-material

[StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-j8tkcv?file=src/app/item-list/item-list.component.ts)

Initially, the Material error works fine. But after adding an item to the list, I need the submitted status to reset. For example, add an item, then click the Add Item button without inputting any text. The error no longer works.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Can you provide more information about your problem? Because I'm trying to reproduce it without success! Thank you!

Comment: Do not work with the html form node directly. Writing `getElementByXy()` is not what you do with angular. Create a form group and call reset on this form group (or on your FormControl if that's the only control.)

Comment: @RicardoRocha - Steps: Submit form > = alert + input marked as invalid > type "abc" and submit form > = item added > submit form again with empty input > ERR: input not marked as invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is only one FormControl, we do not need a FormGroup. The FormControl is bound to the input. The FormControl can be used to perform all actions onto the input. There are lot of other unwanted code which have been removed in the StackBlitz below:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-futhpe

Answer (score 0):

[This accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48216330/angular-5-formgroup-reset-doesnt-reset-validators) is what I was looking for. You need to reset the `FormGroupDirective`.

[New StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-m1pqtb?file=src/app/item-list/item-list.component.ts) with working example (some other code changes as well).