# clearvalidators() not working as expected along with form reset method in angular

Tags: angular

I am trying to clear form values as well as validation messages from form on radio button change event but it still display validation message while the form control is empty

```
 changePaymentType(type) {
    this.myForm.reset();
    this.myForm.clearValidators();
    this.myForm.updateValueAndValidity();
```

[form image after reset and clearvalidator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4fFgX.png)

this is the output that I get after reset() and clearvalidator() method get executed.

If I execute the code in a for loop on each control it do work but then validation stop working on the form controls.

```
 <input type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Card Name"
               formControlName="cardName">
        <div class="font-red" *ngIf="(f.cardName.touched || f.cardName.dirty || validateCard)  && f.cardName.errors">
          {{getValidationErrors(f.cardName.errors)}}
        </div>
```

Thats the html code of form control

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular 5 FormGroup reset doesn't reset validators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48216330/angular-5-formgroup-reset-doesnt-reset-validators)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you're missing the updateValueAndValidity() function that needs to be called after updating the validators. Moreover, it is recommended to clear validators of controls instead of whole formGroup;

```
this.myForm.get('cardName').clearValidators();
this.myForm.get('cardName').updateValueAndValidity();
```

Comment: thanks for replying, even after using updatevalueandvalidity() it is working same as above

Comment: yes in for loop, do i have to use setValidators again for displaying validation back ?

Comment: yes, you have to compose validators and call updateValueAndValidity function again.

Answer (score 0):

You have to execute `updateValueAndValidity()`.

```
this.myForm.reset();
this.myForm.clearValidators();
this.myForm.updateValueAndValidity();
```

Comment: thanks for replying, even after using updatevalueandvalidity() it is working same as above