# Angular Form reset issue

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I am new in Angular and I have a FromGroup:

```
inputData: FormGroup;

.....

this.inputData = this.formBuilder.group({
        vorname: ['', [Validators.required]],
        nachname: ['', [Validators.required]],
        ort: ['', [Validators.required]],
        anschrift: ['', [Validators.required]],
        geburtsdatum: ['', [Validators.required]],
        gueltigAb: ['', [Validators.required]]
    });
```

And I have a button to clear the form content with this method:

```
protected onClearFormContent() {
    this.inputData.reset();
}
```

Now, when I click the button, the input data from the form get cleared but since all the controls are mandatory, the form looks like this:

[image]

I do not want my input fields marked as invalid because of the empty content, since the whole form has been reloaded.

After searching for a while, I have founded this solution:

```
protected onClearFormContent() {
    this.inputData.reset();
    Object.keys(this.inputData.controls).forEach(key => {
        this.inputData.controls[key].setError(null);
    });
}
```

But then the validation does not work later on, and it does not matter if I leave one of the mandatory fields empty, it does not get marked as invalid.

I tried to play with touched / untouched values, but did not help.

Can please somebody help how to solve this?

Thanks a lot in advance!

---

**SOLUTION**

Ok, so, the solution from @ammad-hassan worked like a charm.
I only needed to change my button from:

```
<button mat-button (click)="onClearFormContent()">Formular leeren</button>
```

To:

```
<button mat-button type="submit">Formular leeren</button>
```

And calling my function like this:

```
(ngSubmit)="onClearFormContent()"
```

Comment: Does it help you ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/48217303/6444705

Comment: @Emilien Unfortunately no

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try calling `this.inputData.markAsUntouched();` instead of setting errors to null after resetting your form. Moreover, instead of `this.inputData.reset()` try calling `this.userForm.resetForm()`. to make this accessible-
declare form as NgForm like this:

```
@ViewChild("userForm") userForm: NgForm;
```

and in your template

```
<form #userForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSaveUser()" novalidate>
    ....
</form>
```

Comment: thank you, but this one I have already tried and did not helped

Comment: updated my answer. try this, it might help

Comment: Die Eigenschaft "resetForm" ist für den Typ "FormGroup" nicht vorhanden.

Comment: resetForm is not accessable for FormGroup

Comment: Ach, it worked. I update my question with the solution. Thanks a lot!